# Windows Server 2019 - Hyper-V: 1NIC for server, 1 NIC for VMs

Tags: networking, hyper-v, nic

and thanks for reading!
I have always been dabbling with networks and I am (very slowly) starting to understand them.
I have at work a windows server 2019 which I am using to understand how networking works, so I can replicate at home (possibly the concepts).

The windows server has 2 x NICs and I have always set up Hyper-V with only 1 NIC and multiple VMs, so this is completely new and obscure for me.

**What I want to do**:
as the title suggests I would like to use **1 NIC to assign to the server** and t**he other NIC for the VMs**, the particular part is the *server would have shares that these VMs can access* and they would all need to be on the same ip range as they will be available internally.

***IDEALLY*** I would be able to set some VMs on NIC1 (with server) and others on NIC2 as I think fit for load balancing.

Now if this is at all possible I don't know, I hope I am asking in the right place.
If you are so kind to answer could you use simple jargon please? Some of the answers I find here are a bit complicated!

I like to think I understand a bit, but then I also realize there are a TON of people who know a lot more!

I have attached a schematic for this!
Thank you very much

[Hand drawn schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtTV7.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would be able to set some VMs on NIC1  and others on NIC2

I am a big fan of just adding **all** your Interfaces to a single Hyper-V switch using [switch embedded teaming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-virtual-switch/rdma-and-switch-embedded-teaming), and just letting Windows automatically distribute the load of the VMs between all your interfaces.

From Powershell

```
Get-NetAdapter
# My physical network interfaces were named NIC1, and NIC2
New-VMSwitch -Name External -NetAdapterName "NIC1","NIC2" -EnableEmbeddedTeaming $true
```

By default this is going create a Virtual interface dedicated to the management (host) OS.

After that is in place just set all your Virtual interafaces in all VMs to use 'External' switch.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer: would the NICs be then connected to the physical switch?
Also hyperv then creates the virtual adapter, I am then unsure of: where does my static IP go? And the dns and gateway?
I’m very confused!

Comment: In this setup, all the physical interfaces, you add to the team would need to be connected to your physical switch.  Assuming you name your Switch 'External' like I do, you will have an interface named `vEthernet (External)` after you create the switch.  That is your interface for the host OS.  You can leave that as DHCP or assign your static IP to that.

Comment: Here is a somewhat generic version of my setup hyper-v 2016+ script https://gist.github.com/zoredache/9eee4b4bbe72ec857de5e4b428ca03c8

Comment: Wow, thanks, so I am tempted to go by this solution of letting windows do the sorting out of the bandwidth, but if I had some heavy usage on a particular VM such as streaming for example (here it's more a intranet access on a particular VM - but you get the point) how would I separate the NIC?

Comment: If you wanted to separate things out, I would probably create two virtual switches in that case using the above method, the second would need a different name.  Just change which interfaces you assign to each switch.

Comment: Thanks I have accepted your answer, you really made my day! All seems to work fine!